# php shopping cart not displaying items in cart?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, cart

I'm trying to implement a php shopping cart on my site. I currently have the products page correctly reading from my database. When the cart is empty, the "There are no items in your cart," text displays, however when the cart has something in it, it displays the headers to this table, but no product information.

```
<form name="cartform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
        <input type="hidden" name="command" />
        <span id="cont_shop">
        <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="window.location.href='../Project/products.php'" />
        </span>
        <div id="formerror"><?php echo $message ?></div>

        <table id="cart_table">
        <?php
            if(count($_SESSION['cart']))
            {
                echo '<tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Options</th>
                </tr>';

                $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);

                for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
                {
                    $product_id = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'];
                    $product_name = get_product_name($dbc,$product_id);
                    $product_price = get_price($dbc,$product_id);

                    if($quantity == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    echo '<tr>
                    <td>' . $product_name . '</td>
                    <td>&#36; ' . $product_price . '</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product' . $product_id . '" value="' . $quantity . '" maxlength="4" size="2" /></td>
                    <td>&#36; ' . $product_price*$quantity . '</td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(' . $product_id . ')">Remove Item</a></td>
                    </tr>';
                }

                echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Order Total: &#36;' . get_order_total($dbc) . '</strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3" id="cart_buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()">
                <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()">
                <input type="submit" value="Complete Order" onclick="complete_order()">
                </td>
                </tr>';
            }

            else
            {
                echo '<tr><td>There are no items in your shopping cart.</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>
        </table>
        </form>
```

When I view the page source, all I see is the HTML render to here:

```
    <table id="cart_table">
    <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Did you do a `view source` in the browser to verify that you've got html coming out? Maybe it's got a syntax error causing the product info to get ignored by the browser. Done any debugging in the code, e.g. `var_dump($_SESSION['cart'])` to see what's really in there? Maybe your quantity field isn't being set properly, so you automatically skip ALL entries in the cart.

Comment: @Marc B The page displays as normal using my HTML. The only thing that doesn't load is the content below the headers of the table. Will a var_dump display when I render the page?

Comment: I mean the html for the table content. does it show up in the page's source? if not, then your code isn't outputting any, and you need to figure out why.

Comment: I don't see `session_start();` anywhere. But I'll bet you have it, right? 99% will say "Yes I have it, it's just not posted in my question".

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, there's a session start at the top of my code.
MarcB when I view the source, the source stops right after the options th closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
     if(count($_SESSION['cart']))
            { 
   ?>
      <form name="cartform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
        <input type="hidden" name="command" />
        <span id="cont_shop">
          <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="window.location.href='../Project/products.php'" />
        </span>
        <div id="formerror"><?php echo $message ?></div>

        <table id="cart_table">
        <?php

                echo '<tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Options</th>
                </tr>';

                $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);

                for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
                {
                    $product_id = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['quantity'];
                    $product_name = get_product_name($dbc,$product_id);
                    $product_price = get_price($dbc,$product_id);

                    if($quantity == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    echo '<tr>
                    <td>' . $product_name . '</td>
                    <td>&#36; ' . $product_price . '</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product' . $product_id . '" value="' . $quantity . '" maxlength="4" size="2" /></td>
                    <td>&#36; ' . $product_price*$quantity . '</td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(' . $product_id . ')">Remove Item</a></td>
                    </tr>';
                }

                echo '<tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Order Total: &#36;' . get_order_total($dbc) . '</strong></td>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3" id="cart_buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()">
                <input type="submit" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()">
                <input type="submit" value="Complete Order" onclick="complete_order()">
                </td>
                </tr>';
             ?>
         </table>
         </form>
      <?php
         }

            else
            {
                echo '<tr><td>There are no items in your shopping cart.</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: @user3042765, could you please explain what does you code do?